# XPages: how can i send data between 2 xpages using post http method?

Tags: request, http-post, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I see that i can pass data between 2 xpages by using url parameters in the first page and then retrieve them from the second xpage by using :
`param.get()`.

How can i send data without showing them in the url and without session scope variable? Can i use post method?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use scoped variables?

Comment: no this is mostly a general question, i am not looking for a specific solution. But i ve read that request scope variables are not always working without problems(i also had problems with request scope in the past) and session scope is not a best practice if you want just request lifetime. this could be a reason. I ve read about createForm=false property and the use of a custom html form. is there any other more out-of-the-box way?

Comment: See Per's answer for what I was planning to suggest. But bear in mind that one trouble with "general questions" is that without knowing the business case for your technical objective, we can't gauge whether your design pattern is sound to begin with. You *can* use `flashScope` to do what you're describing, but there might be a much better way to deliver the functionality that is the reason *why* you're trying to do what you're describing.

Comment: I think flashscope works just inside single NSF. And yes, you can use POST, that will work cross NSF/server boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create and use a flashScope implementation in XPages. See  http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/andyc/entry/a_flash_scope_for_xpages for more details.

The flashScope scope variables lives from one xpage to the next.

**Update april 2016**

The blog post is no longer available. You can find an implementation of flashScope in the [XPages Scaffolding project](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding) on Github. You need to add the following to your code:

- a flashScope phase listener similar to [this flashScope phase listener](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/42d13b3f36b86719c2f4720d5d8db7aa5817a8a1/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/main/java/frostillicus/xsp/FlashScopePhaseListener.java).
- entries in your faces-config similar to [those in the XPages Scaffolding project](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/42d13b3f36b86719c2f4720d5d8db7aa5817a8a1/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/main/java/frostillicus/xsp/config/frostillicus-faces-config.xml) for a flashScope managed bean and for the phase listener.

Comment: Hi,
The link above seems to be broken.
Could you please let me know if there are any alternate link or sample code.